# save get image in android e find the path

Tags: android

I use these methods for save and get an Image

```
public void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap b, String name) {   
   FileOutputStream out;
     try {
         out = context.openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
         out.close();

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

and this is the getImage

```
public Bitmap getImageBitmap(Context context, String name) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(name);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        fis.close();

        return b;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

this way is fine for me, but now I need to upload the image on a server, and for this I need the path of the image.
Do you know how can I found it, without create a new image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Call `getFileStreamPath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath%28java.lang.String%29) with your filename that you used with `openFileInput()` and `openFileOutput()`.